# Error response when running a Docker image

Tags: docker, docker-image

**Problem 1:**

I am trying to run a Docker image from https://github.com/aardk/jupyter-casa following their instructions:

```
docker run --rm -p 8888:8888 -i -t -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY penngwyn/jupytercasa /bin/sh -c "jupyter notebook"
```

However I get the following error:

> /usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint kickass_bardeen (90b2146f333df156436337177a0ffc87de7a231e3653b593229dcefadf45293f): exec: "docker-proxy": executable file not found in $PATH.

I tried to softlink docker-proxy-current as docker-proxy

```
sudo ln -s docker-proxy-current docker-proxy
```

but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Problem 2:**

After getting the error, I try running the above docker line again, but get:

> Bind for 0.0.0.0:8888 failed: port is already allocated

How do I free up 8888?

I am running docker on: Scientific Linux 7.4 (Nitrogen) through a vncviewer from another pc

Comment: What does `docker ps` show you? You might have another instance of this container running on 8888 that you thought was killed, but it isn't.

Comment: `docker ps` shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I was using an older version of Docker (pre-installed by the systems admin). Upgrading to the latest version solved the problems.